# Bleaching Dyneema/Spectra

Tags: cleaning

My white full Dyneema backpack is old and dirty and stained.  How do I clean it?

Can I wash it in chlorine bleach or some other fabric bleaching chemical? If so, how?
Even if the bleaching agent does not damage the fabric, is there a chance it could damaged seams and stitching?

Comment: Who manufactured it?  Dyneema a brand of fabric specifically, so it would be necessary to know who actually assembled the pack (so that I can check on the seems and stitching).  The Dyneema itself is safe to bleach.

Answer (score 3):

To wash any pack, you are pretty safe using a large commercial front-loading washer (found at many laundr-o-mats in the US) and regular detergent, then letting it drip-dry. Remove any removable buckles/straps first to prevent loss/damage (to both the pack and machine).

For your white pack, a few thoughts:

1. White outdoor gear is going to get dirty. Wear it as a point of pride it has done more than just sit in your closet ;)
2. Dyneema(tm) is reportedly bleach safe.
3. In general, bleach is pretty safe on any non-organic material. Bleach works by breaking down organics (which is why cotton shirts/socks tend to get thinner over time.) If your stitching is organic (cotton, wool, etc) bleach could weaken them over time.